# Cobalt decoding lossless webp failed with the test of https://2018-dot-qual-e.appspot.com/webp.html in cobalt-release_11

Tags: cobalt

I used cobalt-release_11 as the cobalt source code, and the test image links is https://2018-dot-qual-e.appspot.com/webp.html , I use the chrome to open image links and all the images decode is ok at my computer, but in Linux OS, I input command "./usr/bin/cobalt/cobalt --url="https://2018-dot-qual-e.appspot.com/webp.html" --allow_http --csp_mode=disable --ignore_certificate_errors", the png, jpeg, lossy images decoder success, but the third lossless webp decoder failed, as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZWMe.jpg)

and I add few logs in DecodeVP8LData(),VP8LDecodeImage(),ProcessRows(),EmitRows(), there are no any errors, the decoded process is normal, but decoded image is not normal. I can't find the reason, Can you help me? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the same issue as discussed in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70876684 .  There, it looks like the problem was solved by manually updating libwebp to version 0.4.2 (from 0.3.1).  This is difficult for us to help track down because we cannot reproduce it on any of our platforms, so if you are able to track down what the issue might be, we would be grateful to know.  What is the hardware, is this a s805 (as was the case in the bug link above)?  Let's move this discussion to that bug.